# Can I load the data for all my tabs when my app launches?

Tags: ios, performance

I have a tab bar application that works fine, but if the app is opened without it having been running in the background, then the tabs are a little slower to open than usual, as they are loading plists.

Is it possible to load all the data into the views when the app launches?

Comment: Yes it is possible but more than likely what you should consider is loading the plists in some sort of outside dataManager that then passes the data to the views when they are requested. This separation of view and data would also allow you to load the data in chunks as well as in the background.

Comment: sorry - really should have said I'm still quite a beginner...didn't fully understand that! :( but thank you for you response

Comment: Alright well basically, I'm assuming you're loading plists in your viewController viewDidLoads am I correct?

Comment: I am, yes. Should I not be?

Comment: You certainly can. But if you want it to load faster you need to do it somewhere else and/or in the background. Then just have your viewController present the data. Check the answer below. You can create a singleton as a dataManager that loads the data outside of your viewControllers. Then in the viewDidLoad just as the dataManager for your data :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a service class from which all of the view controllers can query. A common method of defining such a helper class is using the singleton design pattern. The singleton pattern allows only one instance of a singleton class to ever be instantiated. Using this method, you know that every other instance that will be making use of this service will be going through this one instance.

Here's the snippet I noramlly use, it might not be the optimal so I invite other users to suggest changes please:

```
//.h:

+ (MySingletonServiceInstance *)sharedInstance;

//.m:

static MySingletonServiceInstance *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (MySingletonServiceInstance *)sharedInstance{
    @synchronized(self){
        if(sharedInstance == nil)
            sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {    
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        //Set up
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now in any other class (such as a view controller that needs some data), you can do something like this:

```
[[MySingletonServiceInstance sharedInstance] doSomething];
```

or

```
NSDictionary *myData = [MySingletonServiceInstance sharedInstance].data;
```

and it will call the same object. I often use singleton objects for loading data and suchlike, whether it's an interface to a web service or to the local CoreData. It's a really useful design pattern and I learned so much by picking it up.

Comment: Thanks for the answers :) I don't fully understand the singleton one, but I will look into it and learn it if I can.

Comment: Cool no worries, once you have MVC design and the singleton pattern down you will be flying.